# Having a rectangle stretched on the y-axis and with two opposite points on the y-axis, how to find out the stretching/scale factor?

Tags: geometry, binomial-coefficients, quadratics, rectangles

So I have a rectangle, that has points A and C on the y-axis, and A at (0,0). Then it is stretched along the y-axis.

I have all new coordinates of the stretched rectangel.

How to calculate the stretch/scale factor used without using sinus-functions? (I assume it will basically have two solutions, but I know the C is always above A, somewhere on a positive y-point.)

(I made a nice graphic, but don't know how to upload it.)

It's not homework. (I'm afraid back at school I would have solved this in like 3 minutes.)

Comment: When "stretched," does point A remain at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Y.Forman In fact point A does remain at (0,0). - If C is unstretched at (0,10) and stretched at (0,20) the stretching/scaling factor would be 2 in y-direction.

Comment: Yup! So what's the question?

Comment: I have all new coordinates of the stretched rectangel. But of the original points I only have A at (0,0). How to calculate the used strechting/scaling factor? Without using any sinus-functions! :)

Comment: I don't think you have enough information. E.g., if C is now at $(0,20)$, it could be it started at $(0,10)$ and the scaling factor is $2$, or it could be it started at $(0,5)$ and the scaling factor is $4$. Same for any other point.

Comment: I have all stretched points' coordinates, and the inner angles are either over or under 90°, and using a graphics program trying to undo the stretching one could see the angles approach 90°, and pass it, and then go on. So only two solutions: The original rectangle, or the mirrored version of the original rectangle to regain 90° angles.

Comment: If you scale a rectangle, the angles always remain constant... I'm afraid I don't understand the question properly. Perhaps you can try to edit your question to be clearer about what "stretching" means.

Comment: @Y.Forman My guess is that OP is using an anisotropic scaling. Instead of multiplying every coordinates by the scale factor, he only multiplies one coordinate... Or maybe use different scale factor for each different coordinate. The way the question is currently phrased, I think he only multiplies the $y$-coordinate by some scale factor, and leaves the $x$-coordinate untouched?

Comment: @N.Bach That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know from the start that your stretch transformation is of the type
$$
T_\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (x,\alpha y)
$$
This transformation maps lines to line, so
you can avoid computing a sine/cosine if you use the dot product properly.

Say your original rectangle is $IJKL$ and after applying the stretch $T_\alpha$ it is mapped to $I'J'K'L'$.
We're going to look for some value $\beta$ such that $T_\beta$ maps
$I'J'K'L'$ back to $IJKL$.

Let $\mathbf u'=\vec{I'J'}$ and $\mathbf v'=\vec{J'K'}$. (The two vectors $\mathbf u'$ and $\mathbf v'$ can actually be the direction vector of any two consecutive sides.)
Let $(u_x',u_y')$ be the coordinates of $\mathbf u'$, and likewise $(v_x',v_y')$ the coordinates of $\mathbf v'$.
If you apply a stretch with scaling factor $\beta$ to $\mathbf u'$ and $\mathbf v'$, and compute their dot product, you end up with
$$T_\beta(\mathbf u').T_\beta(\mathbf v') = u_x'v_x'+\beta^2u_y'v_y'$$
In particular, when that dot product is zero you know that the two directions
$T_\beta(\mathbf u')$ and $T_\beta(\mathbf v')$ are orthogonal.
That means that the $\beta$ values that annul that dot product have either inverted your initial stretch, or given you the symmetric configuration.
In other words, $\left\lvert \alpha\beta \right\rvert = 1$.

Comment: Ty a lot! I will take a bit of time to implement it in my little computer algorithm I'm writing; for the case I missed something important in my question, just after done writing I will come back and accept the answer. - The solution looks even a little bit easier than I expected. Before asking here I was about to recreate the dot-product procedure. (Reinventing the wheel.)